# React is not defined when trying to load UI component from CDN

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, cdn

I'm trying to load a react component from a CDN but during the loading, I'm getting "React is not defined" error:
[image]

**Notes:**

- The CDN have external dependencies on React and ReactDOM

**More info:**

1. Tried to find a solution here and in Chat GPT but both didn't have merit.
2. Since the CDN package has a dependency on react and react-dom I added to the index file the lines below, but got an error on multiple versions of react.

   ```html
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
   ```

- I think that something is missing in the Webpack, Tried to add externals but it didn't work.
- I tried to add babel configurations as I read it somewhere (see below) it didn't work

  ```
  "@babel/preset-env",
  ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}]
  ```

What is the right way to config my Webpack to use my project's react as an external react to my CDN?

I managed to show my components by adding:

```js
window.React = React;
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
```

but this is causing a weird UI behavior and also this is not a solution good enough for production code.

- This is an example for the index file with one of my tries to give the CDN React & ReactDOM:

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <!-- this is my try to add react & react dom but this is giving me multiple react instances error -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  ....
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- this is an example of my component:

  ```
  import React from "react";
  import { MyComponent } from "@sci/my-cdn";

  const MeetingRecapSpeakersContainer = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Meeting Recap Speakers Container</h1>
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default MeetingRecapSpeakersContainer;
  ```
- Here is an example of my package.json:

  ```json
  {
    "name": "@msteams/components-meeting-recap-speakers",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Meeting Recap Speakers Component",
    "main": "index.ts",
    "module": "index.ts",
    "private": false,
    "sideEffects": false,
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "node ../../../tools/build/cli/transpile.js",
      "lint": "node ../../../tools/build/cli/run-package-eslint.js",
      "test": "node ../../../tools/build/cli/run-package-unit-tests.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      ...
      "react": "^17.0.2",
      "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
      "react-is": "^17.0.2",
      "@sci/my-cdn": "1.20230828.1", // This is my CDN
      "@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.11.0"
    },
  }
  ```

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: which code?
it is a very large project, I basically loading the CDN from a react component of the project, not sure the code is relevant, i probably don't understand something

Comment: The error you get for example Root.tsx

Comment: the error is coming from the CDN, the issue is that I'm trying to load cdn where the cdn using react and react-dom as external  library and the component i'm loading the cdn from is also using react.
adding in the component the following lines helped:

windows.React=React
window.ReactDOM=ReactDOM
after import helped but caused weird behavior on other components, also it seem not good enough for production, is there any webpack configuration which can help in this situation?

Comment: We can't address issues in code we can't see, so please do [edit] the post to include all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. Look at the error stacktrace to see what code/components are part of the problem, like `Root.tsx` that was already pointed out, perhaps also `TextDirectionContext.esm.js` (*though I suspect this is part of the code you are pulling via CDN*).

Comment: @Coyote as Drew pointed out there's a file called TextDirectionContext in the error log, can you share the source code?
There are a lot of reasons why this error might happen, one of them is using a hook inside a .ts or .js file instead of .tsx/jsx

Comment: @DrewReese - I edit my thread, addressing more accurate information about my issue, i hope that this is enough for you to understand.

Comment: Share a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "A very large project" is just a way to get around the actual problem. Shake up your project and pin-point the issue with as minimal code as possible. Otherwise nobody would be able to help you out in a meaningful way.

Comment: added code samples

Comment: React is already a project dependency, so there's no need for it to be brought in via CDN and it should be removed from your index.html file. ***What*** CDN component are you referring to? Please [edit] your post to include a ***complete*** [mcve] enough a reader here can fully understand what you are trying to do and where the issue(s) is(are) introduced.

Comment: when removing the react from the index i'm getting the error i mentioned. i'm trying to load a private cdn we created. this cdn is already loaded from a different place but the difference between them is that i'm loading my component directly and the other reference load it from an iframe.
in the reference it looks like they copied with the webpack react and react-dom into vendor folder and loaded it from there.
the person who wrote it left so i cant ask, hence asking here

Answer (score 0):

#### First, of all Peer Dependencies

To ensure your library works well with React-based apps, you should adjust your library's `package.json`. Move `react` and `react-dom` from "dependencies" to "peerDependencies" and specify the versions you have installed:

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^18",
  "react-dom": "^18"
}
```

While this may seem unusual, it's considered a best practice. Your package doesn't need to include its own React instance; it should assume that consumers have it. You can find more information on peerDependencies in the [NodeJs documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies)

#### Why are you seeing this issue?

You are importing `react` from a CDN and at the same time has another from your `node_modules`. While not recommended, if you prefer to keep your CDN approach, you can refer to the [Webpack documentation on externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) for guidance.

#### Resolving the Issue with Webpack

A more robust solution is to address this issue directly with Webpack. Add the following alias within the resolve property of your Webpack configuration:

```
 alias: {
   react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
 }
```

You can remove the CDN import after this
Check out the [GitHub issue discussing multiple instances of React](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991).

Answer (score -1):

In the shared details you've mixed two things. You are using react from CDN and you also have package.json file in your project which will install react in node_modules. You need to choose whether you want to use react from CDN or from node_modules. Also, If you choose to use react from CDN then you'll need a compiler to compile your components to browser supported language.

Here is an example repository which demonstrates. How to use react from CDN :
[Click Here](https://github.com/PatoGordo/react-cdn)